# ¿Cómo convertir un archivo html en un grafico que contenga cajas correspondiente a la estructura de etiquetas y ids?

Tags: html, dom

Luego de hacer algunas páginas web me surge la necesidad de dar mantenimiento a algunas de ellas; dado que no he sido muy bueno para documentar me vendría bien alguna herramienta en la que pueda cargar mi archivo HTML y que me mostrara una vista de mis etiquetas   y demás aiquetas HTML como en la siguiente imagen ... podría programar un script con expresiones genéricas en PHP pero la verdad no me creo que no exista una herramienta que ya lo haga, así que espero me puedan ayudar ... saludos. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

encontré este aplicativo, espero que te sea útil. Maneja varios tipos de archivos web y los convierte en diagramas de tipo arbol. Su principal funcionalidad se aprovecha con archivos del tipo XML. Te dejo el link:

https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/rng_visual_schema_editor.html

Por lo pronto ami me sirve mucho usar Notepad++ y hacer busquedas entre todos los archivos abiertos, o usando el visual studio, hacer busquedas en toda la solucion. Si lo que quieres es ver el codigo de manera "visual" en tiempo real tambien tenes el adobe dreamweaver.